# Error in splitting a block of data using Python

Tags: python

I have a parsed through a file and I need to split the data according to `LogType` .Below is my data:

```
===================================================================================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD
20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver.
20/06/21 12:19:40 INFO eas
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started

===================================================================================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
```

I have applied a code which results in some error in splitting of data.Below is the code I applied:

```
def parse_container(text,full_text_lines,filter_log_types=None,filter_content_types=None):
    results={}

    first, rest  = text.split('\n', 1)
   #print(rest)      #rest is the block of data mentioned above
    results['id'] = first
    all_log_types = re.compile('^(?=LogType:)',flags=re.MULTILINE).split(rest)
    print(all_log_types)
```

The output I got:

```
['========================================================================\nLogType:container-
localizer-syslog\nLog Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020\nLogLength:0\nLog Contents:\n\n
LogType:stderr\nLog Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020\nLogLength:3000\nLog Contents:\n20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD \n20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver.\n
20/06/21 12:19:40 INFO eas\n20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started\n \n']
['========================================================================\nLogType:container-
localizer-syslog\nLog Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020\nLogLength:0\nLog Contents:\n\n']
```

The output I need:

```
['========================================================================\n','LogType:contain
er-localizer-syslog\nLog Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020\nLogLength:0\nLog Contents:\n\n', 
 'LogType:stderr\nLog Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020\nLogLength:3000\nLog Contents:\n20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD \n20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver.\n20/06/21 12:19:40 INFO eas\n20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started\n \n']

['========================================================================\n','LogType:contain
    er-localizer-syslog\nLog Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020\nLogLength:0\nLog Contents:\n\n']
```

In my output you can see I am getting `\n` at the beginning of LogType but I need to split according to the LogType by `comma`.

In the expected output you can see that the data has been split according LogType by  `,`

I am using Python 2.6.6 . Please help me to solve this issue . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could easily split the logs using regular expressions in `python`. The following code splits the logs by an `or` of two conditions.

Condition1: Multiple occurrences of `=` followed by a `\n`

Condition2: 2 occurrences of `\n`

If any of the conditions is satisfied, we get the output. `filter` will remove any empty strings returned by the `split` and return an `object`. This `object` is then converted to a `list`.

```
import re

text = """===================================================================================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD
20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver.
20/06/21 12:19:40 INFO eas
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started

===================================================================================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
"""


output = list(filter(None, re.compile('[=]+.\n|\n\n').split(text)))

print(output)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['LogType:container-localizer-syslog\nLog Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020\nLogLength:0\nLog Contents:', 'LogType:stderr\nLog Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020\nLogLength:3000\nLog Contents:\n20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD\n20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver.\n20/06/21 12:19:40 INFO eas\n20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started', 'LogType:container-localizer-syslog\nLog Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020\nLogLength:0\n']
```

Comment: It  gives correct output when I have  only one block but fails if have many blocks like I have mentioned above in the question.

Comment: I encounter a similar problem in another area. Can you help me to solve that ?  This is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901200/error-in-splitting-a-file-block-data-in-python

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple logs in one file, try this:

```
import re

results={}
logs = re.split('^=', text, 0, re.MULTILINE)

for log in logs:
    if (len(log) > 0):
        first, rest = log.split('=\n')
        print('first', first)
        print('rest',rest)
        print("\n\n")
```

Output:

```
first =================================================================================
rest LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD
20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver.
20/06/21 12:19:40 INFO eas
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started



first =================================================================================
rest LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
```

Comment: Thanks Donald! But I am still getting the same output.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this :     all_log_types = re.compile('^(?=LogType:)',flags=re.MULTILINE).split(rest)

Comment: @Lekshmi, the 2nd line looks correct too. I tried it and got the results you are looking for. I added something in my answer for you to try to help narrow down the problem

Comment: As you said I think my text source is a problem I think so .Is there a way to solve this ? Because I must perform this operation on the given file . I have added some portion to the question for better understanding.  Or can you suggest some way to solve this error ?

Comment: I added another string to match in my example above, "=$", which should find the last "=" at the end of the first line and split on that, see if that helps.

Comment: No, It still gives the same output

Comment: Ok, maybe the problem was you were trying multiple logs in the same file as your example shows now. I modified my answer above to work on multiple logs in the same file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Donald! I have encountered a similar problem in another area.Can you please help me to solve that ? This is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901200/error-in-splitting-a-file-block-data-in-python

Answer (score 0):

you can use this  as per your question .

```
text=text.replace('=','')
 all_log_types=text.split('\n\n') # splitting based on an Empty line
 print(all_log_types)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Syed. I have got my output partially. But I have that  first line '===============' which is still  joined to my first LogType . How to remove that ?

Comment: if you dont want '===' , then you can use this  text=text.replace('=','')
 text=text.replace('=','')  # removing '='
all_log_types=text.split('\n\n') 
print(all_log_types)