# Error in splitting a file block data in Python

Tags: python

I have parsed a file and I need some help in splitting a data in it. Below is my data:

Block of data:

```
blank space
20/06/25 12:19:33 ERROR datasources
20/06/25 21:12:23 ERROR  sadasdfsd
blank space
blank space    
20/06/25 12:19:33 WARN  asda
20/06/25 21:12:23 ERROR asdasdfsd
20/06/25 12:20:33 WARN  asda
blank space
```

I have mentioned `'blank space'` for better understanding.In my data there will be empty space there

The code I tried:

```
def parse_log_contents(text,full_text_lines,filter_content_types=None):
    #print(text) #Above block of data
    messages = re.compile('^(?=\d+/)',flags=re.MULTILINE).split(text)
    print(messages)
```

The output I got:

```
['']
['20/06/25 12:19:33 ERROR datasources\n20/06/25 21:12:23 ERROR  sadasdfsd']
['']
['']
['20/06/25 12:19:33 WARN  asda\n20/06/25 21:12:23 ERROR asdasdfsd\n20/06/25 12:20:33 WARN  asda']
['']
```

Expected Output:

```
['']
['', '20/06/25 12:19:33 ERROR datasources\n', '20/06/25 21:12:23 ERROR  sadasdfsd']
['']
['']
['', '20/06/25 12:19:33 WARN  asda\n','20/06/25 21:12:23 ERROR asdasdfsd\n','20/06/25 12:20:33 WARN  asda']
['']
```

I use python 2.7 in Linux Environment

In my output you can see I wasn't able to split the errors by delimiter `comma(,)`.

Also I need a empty `''` in front of those messages which I will need later for other processing .

Please help me to sort this issue.Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Comment: I call that from another function .I can add my complete code if you want for better understanding

Comment: When I test your code it is already splitting the lines closer to what you want: https://repl.it/repls/DrabWetPreprocessor#main.py

Comment: Yeah I also got the right answer when I execute it in my PC but when I work in another environment I was not able to get the right answer. I think this type of format is not getting executed correctly there. Is there any alternate method to do this ?

Comment: Make sure you are using raw string starting with `r`. Then you could try splitting with `r'(^|\n)(?=\d+/)'` instead.

Comment: By using that I am able to partial output like this ['20/06/25 12:19:23  ERROR datasources','\n','20/06/25 21:12:23 ERROR  sadasdfsd']

Comment: I don't want the \n to be separate value and also I need to add ' ' in front of the message

Comment: when I test code then I get the same result as @jdaz in `repl.it`. I can get similar result (but not exactly the same) with `'^(?=\n+)$'` and it is not `'^(?=\d+/)'` which you have. So there are two posibilities (1) you have something different then `'^(?=\d+/)'` in code (2) for some reason `re` works in different way but I don't know why. In question you could describe: system (Windows, Linux, Mac) and its version, Python version

Comment: it looks like you first split it on empty lines `^\n` and later you forgot to use `'^(?=\d+/)'` on every item to split them.

Comment: if you split text on empty lines and next you run `parse_log_contents` then I have only one idea - you send wrong text to `parse_log_contents`. It seems you send full text but you should send splited items in `for`-loop.

Comment: Yeah I think the 're' works different in Linux and I use Python 2.7. Because I also encountered the same problem in another area  .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894389/error-in-splitting-a-block-of-data-using-python  In this place also i enountered similar problem

Comment: I think from the above similar question you can get a better understanding. I changed that function code with the solution I accepted and I send text  according to that. May be that be a problem  ? If needed I can post full code